# Firebase notification wih a url

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

How I can send a link inside a notification, then when the user clicks in the notification opens the link with the browser?

I using xamarin forms to develop my app, i already can send notifications from firebase and they are received by the users.

I used this plugin :
https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in the notification will pass to the `MainActivity` by `Intent` when you click the notification. You could get the data in `MainActivity` and use the `intent` to open the browser.

For example, I set the data key is `url` and the value is `https://www.google.com/`.
The code in `MainActivity`:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        var intent = Intent;
        if (intent.Extras != null)
        {
            var url = intent.Extras.Get("url");
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse(url.ToString()));
            StartActivity(browserIntent);
        }
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);
    }
```